# Where can I find the light damage threshold of a specific material (in this case, latex)?

Tags: resource-recommendations, material-science, wavelength, data

I am a part of the University of Maryland Balloon Payload Program, which sends student-built payloads via helium weather balloon to the upper atmosphere. I am interested in developing an Early Flight Termination System to burst a weather balloon from close quarters while in flight.

In order to do this, I am considering using a laser or LED at the specific resonant wavelength of latex (the material of the balloon), held at least about a meter and at most seven meters away from the balloon material. Upon transmission from the host payload, it would activate and burn through the latex, rupturing the balloon and terminating the flight.

To do this, I need the best wavelength of light with which to damage latex. Where could I find a absorbance or reflectance curve for latex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For materials like latex, it may be unlikely that you will find published values for the absorbance/reflectance curve.  Even if you did, you would have to know if the latex they used was the same as the latex you intend to use, as the properties may be quite different.

One more note; latex is quite a complicated molecule, which will not have one "resonant frequency".  I might guess it will have very broad absorbance over the visible spectrum, and you would be better to increase your overall laser intensity than waste time examining which frequency laser is the best.

For reference, I give you [this example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZ9voswS4w0), where the color of these (otherwise identical?) balloons plays a significant role in the absorption.  You might do better to paint a patch with absorptive material if you really want to use a laser to pop your balloon.

Comment: Thank you, I will just have to use a higher wattage laser then, or find some spectroscopy lab on campus.

Comment: The color patch is a good idea. Some experiments would seem to be in order with the lasers you can easily obtain.